# Issue with ui-router while grammatically changing states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a small app that uses ui-router to set up some states in the way seen below:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/dashboard"), 
 $stateProvider.state("app", {
     url: "/app",
     templateUrl: "wwwroot/Views/app.html",
     resolve: loadSequence("chartjs", "chart.js", "chatCtrl"),
     "abstract": !0,
     data: {
         requireLogin: true
     }
 }).state("app.dashboard", {
     url: "/dashboard",
     templateUrl: "wwwroot/Views/dashboard.html",
     resolve: loadSequence("d3", "ui.knob", "countTo", "dashboardCtrl"),
     title: "Dashboard",
     ncyBreadcrumb: {
         label: "Dashboard"
     },
     data: {
         requireLogin: true
     }
 ...
}).state("login", {
     url: "/login",
     template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-right-big smooth"></div>',
     "abstract": !0,
     data: {
         requireLogin: false
     }
}).state("login.signin", {
     url: "/signin",
     templateUrl: "wwwroot/Views/login_login.html",
     resolve: loadSequence("loginCtrl"),
     title: "Login",
     data: {
         requireLogin: false
 }
```

I am then trying to always redirect to the `login` state in the case that the user is not identified by doing something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    var requireLogin = toState.data.requireLogin;
    if (requireLogin && $rootScope.user.name === 'Unknown') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login.signin');
    }
});
```

Every time I try to run this app it starts at `Index.aspx` and due to the `otherwise` command it goes at `/app/dashboard`. The state change is picked up and because I have not identified myself I get redirected to the login page. After that for some reason I get immediately redirected to `/app/dashboard` again. This causes the state change to be picked up again, so it takes me to the login page once more... and so on.

For some reason the `otherwise` command is firing up for every link that I press (state that I change).

What is causing the second immediate redirection to `/app/dashboard`?

Comment: is /app/dashboard your default state? does login.signin exist? Please show the (relevant) rest of your state setup

Comment: @FelixMelix I added the login state on my original question. Hope it is of some help.